# How to choose a WCF binding?

Tags: .net, wcf, binding, wcf-binding

WCF binding chooser algorithm

I have watched a speak at a TechEd conference that showed a simple algorithm for choosing a WCF binding. I can't find this algorithm but I remember some of the main ideas:

1. If your WCF service will have non-.NET clients choose Http Soap
2. If your WCF will have .NET clients in other machines choose Net Tcp
3. If your WCF will have .NET clients in the same machine choose Message Queue

Can anyone provide a link to the full version of this algorithm?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Something like that maybe?

[WCF Binding Decision Chart](http://architectopia.blogspot.com/2008/01/wcf-binding-decision-chart.html)

[WCF Binding Decision Chart http://img109.imageshack.us/img109/4686/wcfbindingdecisionchart.png](http://img109.imageshack.us/img109/4686/wcfbindingdecisionchart.png)

Marc

Comment: Disconnected as in : you drop off a message into a queue, but you don't get back a response right away. The message might be in the queue for a while before the service on the other end picks it up and works on it.

Answer (score 7):

I found another version of the algorithm:

https://mohammedatef.files.wordpress.com/2009/06/wcfbinding.jpg
[image: https://mohammedatef.files.wordpress.com/2009/06/wcfbinding.jpg]

Answer (score 1):

they have the speaks and the presentation on CD (if you participated).
they usually sell the complete DVD after the conference ends.

I think a better question would be - to present your case and have one of the experts recommend (or read Juval Lowy book on wcf.)

I go for net.tcp every time (but i don't mix with non-dot net clients...)
both on the same machine and outside.

This algorithm is a recommendation and not a must know...