# Overview of WCF binding availability

Tags: wcf, binding

Is there any place that gives a full list of which WCF bindings are supported in which scenarios.

For example:

- Net.tcp is not supported in IIS 6
- wshttpbinding is not supported in Silverlight (version 2?)
- Some bindings are only supported if you have framework 3.5
- In some cases the binding is supported, but not all functionality in the binding

Would be really nice with a table you could hang on the wall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have came acoss a decision chart but it does not cover the things you want

[How to choose a WCF binding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828829/how-to-choose-a-wcf-binding)